# How do I say "Come on" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How do I say "Come on" in German? I would like to say it in this context:

> Come on, you can do it!

My best guess:

> Komm schon, du kannst es schaffen!

Are there any alternatives for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Na los, du schaffst das! Komm schon! Mach schon!

Answer (score 3):

One way of saying this is:

> Komm schon, du kannst es.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness I want to add there are two flavors of "Come on", the first one is supporting as you usually do it for sports and was already translated above. The second one is doubtful and questioning:

> Ach komm! Wirklich? Bist du sicher?

Comment: *Komm schon* with a different intonation works in both situations.